# Using MXUnit or is there another way to display coldfusion output using Intellij IDEA 15

Tags: intellij-idea, coldfusion, mxunit

I'm loving IntelliJ because I also work with MySQL and the integration into one UI is great. Seems that IntelliJ works nicely with ColdFusion as well. I'm just hoping to successfully use MXUnit, but I seem to be getting an error upon testing. My main goal is just being able to display the output directly in IntelliJ instead of outputting in a browser.

My test site path: `/Applications/ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/Test/test.cfc
Error http://localhost/mxunit-launcher.cfc?method=executeTestCase&componentName=test`

Seems like I have to add in a mapping, maybe in CF Admin, because the path and web path don't match but I haven't done that before if that's the case. Here's a screenshot of input in IntelliJ, and the output at the bottom of the screenshot when running the debugger:

[image: Screenshot of input in intellij and output at the bottom of the screenshot when running debugger]

Thanks for any feedback on what I might be missing.